# Amazon VPC Endpoint for AWS Appflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue, amazon-vpc, endpoint

We have a Glue Python Shell Pipeline Job trying to invoke AWS AppFlow through boto3 APIs. The challenge we have is that we need to design our solution **without the need for internet access within Glue**

Previously we had challenges in upgrading the boto3 APIs in AWS Glue Shell to the latest version **without internet**. But then we have found the solution and documented in the following link. In our architecture, we are using AWS Python Shell as our lightweight Datapipeline Engine leveraging boto3 APIs

[Git Glue Boto3 Bug & Solution](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2566#issuecomment-732333714)

The following Appflow API python code is working perfectly fine in our local Jupyter Notebooks, as AWS App flow API is invoked over the internet.

```
##Extra code as per above link to update boto3 version as well, which is omitted
```

```py
    import boto3
    
    print(boto3.__version__)    
    
    client=boto3.client('appflow')
    response=client.describe_flow(
        flowName='sf_non_pii'
        )
```

But while we use the same code in AWS Glue, it is failing as it is not able to access the internet.

> **botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://appflow.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/describe-flow"**

Please find the logs below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/botocore/httpsession.py", line 263, in send
    chunked=self._chunked(request.headers),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 386, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 735, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 309, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 167, in _new_conn
    % (self.host, self.timeout),
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5f8802c0f0>, 'Connection to appflow.us-east-2.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 123, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(temp_file_path, run_name='__main__')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-a3cgmro3/ref_appflow.py", line 44, in <module>
  File "/tmp/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/tmp/botocore/client.py", line 663, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/tmp/botocore/client.py", line 682, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/tmp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/tmp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 137, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/tmp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 256, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/tmp/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/tmp/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/tmp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/tmp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/tmp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/tmp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/tmp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/tmp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/tmp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/tmp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 269, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/tmp/botocore/httpsession.py", line 287, in send
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://appflow.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/describe-flow"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 142, in <module>
    raise e_type(e_value).with_traceback(new_stack)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

We had faced similar issues for Redshift, AWS Athena, SSM, etc. But for these services, we have VPC endpoints available. Creating the endpoints enabled our glue job to connect privately within the VPC. Please refer to the link below for supported products

[AWS services that you can use with AWS PrivateLink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/integrated-services-vpce-list.html)

But since Appflow is a newer product, we do not have endpoint, even though some unclear documentation regarding a throwaway create and delete VPC endpoint as below

[Private Amazon AppFlow flows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/private-flows.html)

**Please let us know how we can invoke boto3 APIs for Appflow without going through the internet.**

Comment: Oh. My mistake. Thus, if there is no vpc endpoint then you have to use internet, either directly or indirectly through some proxy.

Comment: AWS adding them one by one. Just few weeks ago they added VPC endpoint for lambda, which is a joy after so many years.

Comment: The proxy does not have to be independent instance or anything complicated. Maybe private API gateway or lambda with vpc endpoint, would suffice.

Comment: Did you mean this solution https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/

Comment: Yes. In this case private api gateway would be the proxy. But with VPC endpoints for lambda now, you can also just invoke lambda privately and the lambda can act as a proxy.